# Implement the move semantic in a derived class from stl vector

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, move

I have the following class which inherits the STL vector:

```
class Vec : public vector<int> {

  public:

    Vec() : vector<int>() {}
    Vec(size_t N) : vector<int>(N) {}
    Vec(Vec&& v) : vector<int>(v) {}

    Vec(const Vec&) = delete;
    Vec& operator = (const Vec&) = delete;
};
```

Basically, `Vec` is a wrapper of STL vector in which the `copy` constructor and assignment are disabled. However, it looks like the move constructor doesn't function correctly by the following:

```
Vec a(100);
Vec b(move(a))
cout << a.size() << " " << b.size();  // here I got "100 100"
```

Is there anything wrong in my `Vec` wrapper? Also, how can I implement the move assignment for my `Vec` class such that `Vec b = a` is assigned by move? I am imagining something like the following but it doesn't work :(

```
Vec& operator = (Vec&& rhs) {
  return move(*this);
}
```

One more catch. When implementing move semantics, should we always avoid using `const` keyword? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Vec() : vector<int> {}` is an error, you need to specify initializer

Comment: `a.size()` Even if your code moved correctly (which it didn't), the value of this would be *undefined*. Moved-from standard library objects are left is a valid but *unspecified* state. So if you want to do something like get the size, you have to clear it to a well-defined state first.

Comment: `Vec(Vec&& v) = default;` is the simplest fix

Comment: Standard library containers are not meant to be inherited from; it seems to me that `Vec` doesn't really achieve anything. The user could still cast to base class to access `std::vector`'s copy and assignment operations, and if you pass a `Vec` as argument to any function expecting a `vector`, that function will still be able to copy and assign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vec(Vec&& v) : vector<int>{std::move(v)} // You missed a `std::move` here
{
}

Vec& operator=(Vec&& v)
{
    vector<int>::operator=(std::move(v)); // Selects base class function
    return *this;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72f5298be6a95f1b)

Answer (score 2):

in your Vec move constructor you are using vector copy constructor.
just chaage this:

```
    Vec(Vec&& v) : vector<int>(move(v)) {};
```

it will work fine.